# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate does not allow to add Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

I want to create a DLL folder where i want to put all my dlls and I need to add a reference to this folder in Visual Studio. But when I right click on the Project-->References.. and then click on Add Reference, only the "Projects" tab appears, empty, and you cannot do anything.
Did anybody have the same problem?

Comment: The strange thing is that this works with a C# project, but not with a C++ one

Answer (score -1):

You just have to choose the Browse tab instead of the Projects tab in Projects > Add Reference.